# WM_LBUTTONDOWN receives different coordinates on different OS with DPI 150

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm trying to send WM_LBUTTONDOWN with coordinates [12, 43] to another DPI Unaware program from my DPI Aware program. Meanwhile I'm using Window-Detective observing the target window.

I find the received coordinates are different between different environments.

1. Environment 1:

   - OS: Windows 10 with 150 DPI
   - Window-Detective shows it receives [8,
     28]
2. Environment 2:

   - OS: Windows 7 with 150 DPI on VMWare
   - Window-Detective shows it receives [12, 43]

When I trying to check DPI awareness on **Environment 2**, The '**DPI Awareness**' column checkbox is **grey-out** in `Process Explorer` of Sysinternals.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels

Comment: "*I'm trying to send WM_LBUTTONDOWN ... to another ... program from my ... program*" - why? What are you ultimately trying to accomplish? There is likely a better way to solve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau it is a 3rd-party grid ctrl, I need to select a row by simulating a left click.

Comment: using messages to simulate user input is not a good idea. Use SendInput() or UI Automation instead